# unable to edit .less file

Tags: razor, less, client-side

i've renamed my .css to .less and referenced the less.js file (version 1.3). I'm unable to edit the .less file, it's almost like it's readonly. Any ideas? thanks

i've got this in my root layout head tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/CSS/mystylesheet.less")"/>
```

and this in the body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/less-1.3.0.min.js")"></script>
```

the css works fine, i just cant make any edits whilst running and when stopped.
Using mvc 3 and razor

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `~` in your path. Either use a relative path or a full path using `file://` if you're working from localhost.

Comment: thanks, i don't understand though, how is it able to find my other stylesheets and script files using ~ just not the less one?

Comment: The other files probably aren't calling any other paths that you've defined, whereas less.js is reading the path you provided for the CSS file and can't workout the path to the file.

Comment: when you are compiling less files client side by inclusion of less.js, what less does is loading the .less files content via ajax call. Ajax calls are forbidden to file system urls, and in usual cases are even restricted to same domain. So best of would be to serve your files on some port, both .html and .less

Comment: i'm still confused. all i'm doing is referencing a js file, i reference atleast 5 other js files in the same way and it works fine, except for the less.js. can you give me an example of how i should reference it?